# Multivariate Weierstrass preparation Theorem?

Tags: power-series, local-fields, weierstrass-preparation

Let $(K,|\cdot|)$ be a complete local field and $\mathcal{O}$ be its ring of integers. Let $C$ be a complete algebraic closure of $K$ and let $\mathfrak{m}:=\{x\in \mathcal{O}_{C}~|~|x|<1\}$ where $\mathcal{O}_C$ is the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_K$ in $C$ and $|\cdot|$ denotes the unique extension of the norm of $K$ to $C$. We let $K^s$ be the separable closure of $K$ in $C$.

Let $f(X)\in \mathcal{O}_K[[X]]$. For every $x\in \mathfrak{m}$, $f(x)$ defines a converging series in $C$ so that one can consider the zeroes of $f(X)$ in $\mathfrak{m}$. By the Weierstrass preparation theorem, one deduces easily that if $f'(0)\neq 0$, then $f(x)=0$ implies $x \in K^s\subset C$.

I would be highly interested in references for a multivariate and higher dimensional version of that result. To fix minds, I would like to know the answer to the following question:

> Let $f(X_1,...,X_n)\in \mathcal{O}_K[[X_1,...,X_n]]^n$ be such that $\operatorname{det}(\partial_i f_j(0,...,0))\neq 0$. Let $(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathfrak{m}^n$. Does $f(x_1,...,x_n)=(0,...,0)$ imply $x_1,...,x_n\in K^s$?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need preparation theorems : if  $\forall y\in a+\mathfrak{m}^N$, $v(f'(y))=r, v(f(y)) > 2(r+N)$ then for all $b\in a+\mathfrak{m}^N$,  doing a gradient descent from $b$, we obtain a root $x$ in the completion of $K[b]$, and approaching $f$ by a polynomial with a simple zero at $b$ we can take $b\in K^s$ so that $x\in K^s$. It works quite the same with your analytic function $O^n\to O^n$.

Comment: What happens if $f=X_1-X_2$?

Comment: Thank you @LaurentBerger, your example fortifies my opinion that the statement has no chance to be true when $f$ belongs to $O[[X_1,...,X_n]]^m$ for n>m. But what if n=m?

Comment: Ah sorry, I read things too quickly. There is a multivariate Hensel's lemma, so if you have a root of your $f_1,...f_n$ in $\mathfrak{m}^n$ you could approximate it by an element of $\mathfrak{m}^n_L$ for $L/K$ finite and large enough, and then use Hensel to show that there is an actual root in $\mathfrak{m}^n_L$. What do you think?

Comment: In my previous comment, add: you'd expect the zeroes of $n$ power series in the $n$ dimensional polydisk to be isolated, so by working in a small ball around one, the Hensel argument tells you that it defined over $K^s$. In the end, this argument is the same as that of @reuns

Comment: I am convinced ! Thank you @LaurentBerger and merry christmas :)